# Why do android methods accept View objects, but the objects are unused?

Tags: android, methods

I'm extremely new to android development, and still a novice in java development; but anyway I'm trying to learn how to develop android apps and I'm trying to understand how everything works together with java and all the resource xml data.

As I was reading some sample android code from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html I noticed that they have a lot of methods like this:

```
public void startDialog(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, DialogActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Why do these methods accept `View` objects, but appear to never be used in the actual method?  How am I to understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `View v` indicates from which view the method is trigerred. For example your `startDialog` method can be used in two or more views' `android:onClick` attribute. Then you can use like

```
public void startDialog(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.view1:
         // do something
         break;
    case R.id.view12:
         // do something
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So that method doesn't use it directly, however, a call to the method can use that `View` parameter (since its a public method)?

Comment: actually I am not clear what are you telling. But I want to tell that, this parameter is used because the method can be invoked from multiple views. to know from which view it is called you need that parameter view. If you see closely you will see that this is mainly used for callbacks/listers. Not usually in your calling methods